# How web element is passed to listener before finding that specific web element

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

`WebDriverEventListener` interface in `Selenium Webdriver` contains a method

```
public void beforeFindBy(By arg0, WebElement arg1, WebDriver arg2);
```

My understanding is that this method gets executed before every time webdriver searching for an element. My question is that how the WebElement argument is passed to the method before finding that specific WebElement

Comment: just to remove confusion .... you want how to implement this using java?

Comment: just want to know the purpose of WebElement argument @noor

Answer (score 1):

The WebElement argument is not the actual element but the element against which the search has to be performed.

In the case of `driver.findElement()`, null will be passed.
In the case of `element.findElement()`, the element will be passed.

Similar for `findElements()` methods. Check out the code for `EventFiringWebDriver` which uses the `WebDriverEventListener`.

Answer (score 0):

If you look below the implementation, i think this will be clear for you:

```
 FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
 EventFiringWebDriver eventDriver = new EventFiringWebDriver(driver);

EventHandler handler = new EventHandler();
eventDriver.register(handler);
```

here Register method will let you register our implementation of WebDriverEventListner to listen to the WebDriver events.

so before doing anything, it will invoke the listener with the initialized driver.

There's a clear documentation on this site about this:

http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/event-listener/